# Protractor test in Angular 6 for login screen

Tags: angular, protractor, gulp-protractor, angular-test

I am new in the Protractor testing for Angular 6 application. I am trying to write the spec test for login page as below.

```
describe('Protractor Login checing ', function() {
    it('should add one and two', function() {
        browser.get('http://localhost:4041/login');
        element(by.model('username')).sendKeys('admin');
        element(by.model('password')).sendKeys('admin');

        element(by.id('login')).click();

        // Here, What should I check whether authentication has been done or not..
        // expect().toEqual('');
    });
});
```

Actually, In My application, once logic is a success, then I will show a success message in snackBar (Angular material) and redirect into dashboard page.

```
// Angular 6 application    
this.snackBar.open(res.message, '', {
                duration: 6000,
              });
```

Here, how should I check in protractor? 
Anyone help me to do this?

Comment: You should check the url has changed or not

Comment: How to check url does have changed or not ?

Comment: the url may change without actually opening the home page. Thus it may be a part of verification but not the only step. What you can check is if your welcome message is present or not, any elements of the home page are present or not etc. To be more specific, I'd need to see what your login page looks like, and what you see after successfully loging in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the `url` has changed or not -

```
describe('Protractor Login checing ', function() {
    it('should add one and two', function() {
    browser.get('http://localhost:4041/login');
    element(by.model('username')).sendKeys('admin');
    element(by.model('password')).sendKeys('admin');

    element(by.id('login')).click();

    browser.wait(waitForUrlChange("http://localhost:4041/dashboard"), 8000, function(){
      browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function (currentUrl) {
          expect(currentUrl.toEqual("http://localhost:4041/dashboard"));
      });
  }));
 });

function waitForUrlChange(url) {
    return function () {
        return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function (currentUrl) {
            console.log(currentUrl);
            return url === currentUrl;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i will check and let u know.

Comment: In Protractor, we should not check the API response rite?

Comment: Yeah.You dont need to check any api res

Comment: It works. Thanks. Btw, even during update the customer, do we follow the same logic that "next page url checking", or anyother possibility to check ?